# Menu Item(s) not showing

Tags: joomla

My Menus in the frontend have gone missing. In the backend, the menu manager shows the number of published menu items  in each menu type but when i click to edit the MenuItem(s), i see no items.
**Why are the MenuItem(s) missing or not visible? How do i make them visible again?**
The site was developed with Version 1.5.10 but the hosting provider(who is not responding) might have upgraded to 1.6 or higher

Comment: Also, check which version you are running. After all, one can see that in the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the menus manager for spaces or special characters in the unique menu names. You should stick to letters and numbers, no spaces, no special characters in menu names. This was not an issue in 1.5.10, the code changed in in a later update that caused this issue.